# How to attach javascript code to this button?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I have created a simple button with this code:

```
  <toolbarpalette id="BrowserToolbarPalette">

      <toolbarbutton id="ok-nav"
                     class="toolbarbutton-1 chromeclass-toolbar-additional"
                     label="&okok;"
                     tooltiptext="&okok;" />
  </toolbarpalette>
```

I need to attach this bookmarklet to that button:

```
javascript:(function(){window.open('http://example.com/test/mm.php?title='+encodeURIComponent(document.title))})();
```

Someone can tell me how can I attach this bookmarklet to that button ?

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to add a `<script>` element in your overlay. Then, in the script, something like the following code snippet will help you perform actions when the button is activated.

```
window.addEventListener("load", function () {
  document.getElementByid("ok-nav").addEventListener("command", function () {
    // do your bookmarklet here
  });
});
```

I think it may be worth reading the [XUL Tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_Tutorial/Overlays), especially the section on overlays :).

Answer (score 0):

I bet you're going to be using this more often. Look into JQuery...

With JQuery you could easily use this:

```
$(document).on('click', '#BrowserToolbarPalette', function(){

window.open('http://example.com/test/mm.php?title='+encodeURIComponent(document.title));

});
```